# QGis Graphic Query builder for PostGis

Tags: postgis, qgis-plugins, query-layer

My question is about availabe QGis Plugins that could help me with the following issue:

I have a PostGis database that has one shapefile as a main table and a lot of tables containing the shapefile's metadata linked to it. I want to query the main shapefile using the information in all the different tables. The result of the multiple-table-query will be a selection on the shapefile / a new shapefile that contains the selection. I can do this by constructing a complex SQL Query in DB Manager and loading the selection as a new layer.

BUT, the future users of my database can't write SQL queries, that's why I am searching for a graphical interface that enables them to construct multiple table queries.

I wonder if I missed any possibility of querying PostGis databases in QGis with help of a graphic query builder. I know that there are several Plugins as:

- DB Manager, that is maybe the most complete but needs to write SQL queries
- PostGis Query Editor, that has the same problem: users need to write SQL
- PostGis Query Builder, that offers a graphic query builder and helps the future user of my database but it is limited to spatial queries
- I have read that there was the "RT Sql Layer Plugin" but it was abandoned when DB Manager was developed, it was the kind of query builder interface that I am searching for but I can't find the code online any more

Comment: have you tried to make a view based on your query?

Comment: That's a little bit what I am doing now. I am not using views because it's a quite complex database with a lot of choices for the selections, so I would need a lot of views. But I wrote a catalogue of queries that can be copy-pasted and combined between each other. However, it needed some days of training for the users, but it will be ok for the moment.